# UITableView to show UIDatePicker in UITableViewCell content view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uidatepicker

This application is both for iPads and iPhones. I have a UITableView Controller in which I have 5 sections. I want to show UIDatePicker inline in the selected cell whenever any of the 5 cells in the whole controller (section 0-> row(0&1), section 3-> row(1&2), section 4 (row 0) are selected. I am new to iOS and any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated. I have gone through apple's documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/datecell/listings/mytableviewcontroller_m.html

and tried to implement this code but did not understand much of it. I have the data for all the 5 sections stored as 5 different arrays in a single array. I have assigned

```
myDatePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
cell.contentView.Frame = myDatePicker.frame;
```

I do not know how to re-size the tableViewCell if the selected cell is one of the datePicker entries and get a done button on toolBar just to save the datePicker value cell. I already have a done button on toolbar to save the entire tableView and segue back to a main controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done by adding a dedicated cell containing the picker that always exists. Use a bool flag to indicate if the picker should be visible or not. The rest of the work is done in the table view height method by returning 0 for the picker row when it should be hidden and the cells real height when it should be visible. Then in the table view row selected method, when the row that shows and hides the picker is tapped the bool is flipped. Followed by matching calls to table view begin and end updates methods to trigger the show/hide animation. I don't have time to find them but there are questions here for this with actual code samples.

Comment: Thanks @Agent00Vic. Really appreciate your suggestion, I will try to find if such solutions exist and will provide the link or the solution whenever I find one.

Comment: Glad to help the search terms you want are inline date picker.